# How to change image after time Interval in Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

So I have a image and I have some counters. And after the total of the counters is above 500 I want to display a other image.

So I have this for the template:

```
  <img src="./assets/noun_Arrow_green.png" alt="Forest" style="width: 50%" />
```

and that image has to change after counter is above 500 with this image:

```
<img src="./assets/noun_Arrow_red.png" alt="Forest" style="width: 50%" />
```

And this is the ts script I have:

```
counters = [100, 200, 10];

increaseTime() {
    this.counters.forEach(() => {
      setInterval(() => {
        this.counters[0]++;
        this.counters[1] = this.counters[1] + 10;
        this.counters[2] = this.counters[2] + 17;

        if (this.counters[0] + this.counters[1] + this.counters[2] > 500) {
          clearInterval();
        }
      }, 3000);
    });
  }
```

But what I have to change?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create one parameter for `src` in component

```
imageSource:string="./assets/noun_Arrow_green.png"
```

in html give this parameter

```
  <img [src]="imageSource" alt="Forest" style="width: 50%" />
```

then in interval change this parameter

```
increaseTime() {
    this.counters.forEach(() => {
      setInterval(() => {
        this.counters[0]++;
        this.counters[1] = this.counters[1] + 10;
        this.counters[2] = this.counters[2] + 17;
        
        if (this.counters[0] + this.counters[1] + this.counters[2] > 500) {
          clearInterval();
          this.imageSource="./assets/noun_Arrow_red.png"
        }
      }, 3000);
    });
  }
```